# Grouping results by id and create new columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which looks something like the following...

```
id           price             condition         sell
21039        20.40             new               0 
21039        20.41             used              1
12378        10.40             new               1
12378        5                 used              0
45898        30.30             new               1
45898        12.20             used              0
```

(**note**: there will only ever be 1 new and used value for each id)

What I am trying to do is group all rows with the same id number but in the process creating new columns for each condition, which should look something like...

```
id           new_price         new_sell          used_price         new_sell
21039        20.40             0                 20.41              1
12378        10.40             1                 5                  0
45898        30.30             1                 12.20              0
```

All that I have come up with is the following query, which looks silly

```
SELECT id, price, condition, 
IF(price > 3, 1, 0)  AS sell
FROM products 
GROUP BY id
```

How can I get the desired affect of the 2nd table.

Comment: Will there only be 2 entries per id in your table, 1 new and 1 used at most?

Comment: I should of mentioned that, there will only 1 new and 1 used value for each id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known as a *pivot table*. It is done with a series of `CASE` statements for each column you need to produce, along with an aggregate `MAX()` or `SUM()` to eliminate NULLs and collapse it down to a single row.

```
SELECT
  id,
  SUM(CASE WHEN `condition` = 'new' THEN price ELSE 0 END) AS new_price,
  SUM(CASE WHEN `condition` = 'new' THEN sell ELSE 0 END) AS new_sell,
  SUM(CASE WHEN `condition` = 'used' THEN price ELSE 0 END) AS used_price,
  SUM(CASE WHEN `condition` = 'used' THEN sell ELSE 0 END) AS used_sell
FROM 
  products
GROUP BY id
```

Without the `SUM()` and `GROUP BY`, you would still get 2 rows per `id`, with each having half its columns (not matched by `condition` in the `CASE`) as `NULL`.  The `SUM()` (could also use `MAX()` in this case) eliminates the NULLs and produces one row since aggregate functions exclude NULL values while the `GROUP BY` groups the rows by `id`.

#### [Here is a working sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21ef1/1) on SQLFiddle.com

#### Update after comment:

To calculate `sell` based on the `price`, just replace the condition in the `sell` `CASE` statements:

```
SELECT
  id,
  SUM(CASE WHEN `condition` = 'new' THEN price ELSE 0 END) AS new_price,
  SUM(CASE WHEN `condition` = 'new' AND price > 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS new_sell,
  SUM(CASE WHEN `condition` = 'used' THEN price ELSE 0 END) AS used_price,
  SUM(CASE WHEN `condition` = 'used' AND price > 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS used_sell
FROM 
  products
GROUP BY id
```

([Updated sample...](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21ef1/2))

Comment: Why have you used SUM im not trying to sum up anything.

Comment: @mk_89 I just added that explanation.

Comment: Wait how do I implement the IF statement condition into this query `IF(price > 3, 1, 0)`

Comment: So you don't want to use the `sell` column in your table, but rather determine it by the price?  I don't understand what that's doing there.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the first table came about from a query, but yes you are correct

Comment: See above. Just a simple change to the `CASE` conditions for those 2 cols.  Though your sample data has no `price` that is actually `<= 3` so all will be `1`.